# In WPF, when visibility is set to Collapsed, the control will not occupy the original location. How can this be archieve in Avalonia

Tags: avalonia

I want to hide a control in Avalonia, and then the space occupied by this control will be occupied by adjacent controls, just like the visibility.Collapsed in WPF.

Comment: Please add your existing code and elaborate.

Answer (score -1):

In Avalonia, use the the property IsVisible (boolean)